# Most efficient way in Python to check if object attributes are assigned DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, attributes, dataframe, inspect

I'm trying to build a list of names of all attributes in a class that are either pandas DataFrames or Series.

The following works but seems slow since it goes through every attribute listed by `dir()` including special methods (the special methods won't be DataFrames so there's no need to check them).  It also seems to execute the `print` statements in other methods, so it is uncertain if the other attributes are being run (not desired).

```
my_instance = MyClass()
pd_objects = [attr for attr in dir(my_instance) if 
              isinstance(getattr(my_instance, attr), pd.DataFrame)
              or isinstance(getattr(my_instance, attr), pd.Series)]
```

Any ideas on a more efficient way to quickly list attributes that are assigned pandas objects, perhaps using the `inspect` module?

Comment: A simple speed up is to use a tuple on the right side of isinstance.  `isinstance(X, (pd.Series, pd.Dataframe))`

Comment: Yeah, __dict__ and this tuple seems to work pretty well.  Edit your answer with a complete solution and I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `__dict__`.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df2': range(5)})
        self.sr2 = pd.Series(range(5))
        self.x = 4
        self.y = 'abc'
        self.z = []


def get_attributes_of_type(cls, types):
    return [i for _, i in cls.__dict__.iteritems() if isinstance(i, types)]
```

Then use it like this:

```
my_A = A()
get_attributes_of_type(my_A, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame))
[0    0
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
 4    4
 dtype: int64,    df2
 0    0
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
 4    4]

get_attributes_of_type(my_A, list)
[[]]

get_attributes_of_type(my_A, str)
['abc']

get_attributes_of_type(my_A, int)
[4]
```

Comment: `__dict__` will skip the special methods, but how about checking for DataFrames?

Comment: Just iterate over the items and check isinstance on them like you did in your original.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a hash-like way to check for DataFrames, or something a bit quicker than iterating a list.

Comment: If you have `n` items in your class, and you need to check all of them for their types, then you have a linear time operation. I don't think you'll beat a `O(n)` solution

Comment: Reminder, I think `iteritems()` is deprecated in Python 3.  You'd need to use `items()`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about any method using `inspect()` module, but rather than `dir()` , you can try using [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)  , it returns the `__dict__` for the object passed to it, so it wouldn't have the special methods, etc. Example -

```
my_instance = MyClass()
pd_objects = [attr for attr in vars(my_instance) if 
          isinstance(getattr(my_instance, attr), pd.DataFrame)
          or isinstance(getattr(my_instance, attr), pd.Series)]
```

Please note, this would still evaluate the properties, since without evaluating the properties, there is no way to determine what it contains/returns (This is most probably the `print` statements you see being executed).

[`vars([object])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) -

> Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: Actually, unlike `dir()`, `vars()`  and `__dict__` this seemed to skip the prints.  Thanks.